# Explorer.exe crash and restart loop after user account rename

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, crash, windows-10-preview

I am using the windows 10 consumer preview (Hoping it is similar enough to windows 8.1 to solve this) and I disconnected my user account from my Microsoft account and renamed it. I then restarted my computer and now explorer.exe keeps crashing and restarting once every half a second. I was able to get a command prompt open and make a new user account with admin privileges, so I have that availible. What is happening?

Answer (score 0):

You damaged your windows. Renaming the account breaks everything. The proper way is to use [Windows Easy Transfer](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/transfer-files-settings-from-another-computer#1TC=windows-7) to capture all user settings and application data, create a new account and restore the settings here again with Windows Easy Transfer.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I just want to clarify: I didn't rename the folder, I renamed it using control panel. I'd think that wouldn't ruin it if it was there.

Comment: do you have a system restore point?

Comment: No. I do not. At the current moment I am just copying my files over manually. Thanks for the help though.